# Cannot start with new line in html

Tags: php, html, css

```
if(!empty($interest)){

foreach ($interest as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div style='float:left; height:130px; width:100px; margin-left:10px; border:solid #f8f8f8; background-color: #f8f8f8;'>";
    echo   "<a class='avatar' href='#'><img width='90' height='40' src=".$value['item_image']."></a>";
        echo   "<div><i>".$value['item_name']."</i></div>";
     echo  "<a href='#' style='text-decoration: none; outline: none;'><span class='label label-success' value=".$value['item_id']." id=".$value['item_id']." onClick='reply_click1(this.id)'>Added</span></a>";
       echo " </div>";


        }
}
```

this is my code I'm printing images horizontally here but i need to print two images per line !
this is my output .
[image]

I need two items per row

[image]

i tried to put `<hr>` and `<br>` it did not help me ! is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($interest as $key => $value) {

$counter++;

if($counter%2==0){
  echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
}

echo "<div style='float:left; height:130px; width:100px; margin-left:10px; border:solid #f8f8f8; background-color: #f8f8f8;'>";
echo   "<a class='avatar' href='#'><img width='90' height='40' src=".$value['item_image']."></a>";
    echo   "<div><i>".$value['item_name']."</i></div>";
 echo  "<a href='#' style='text-decoration: none; outline: none;'><span class='label label-success' value=".$value['item_id']." id=".$value['item_id']." onClick='reply_click1(this.id)'>Added</span></a>";
   echo " </div>";


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `float:left` css property, you must write a `<br style="clear:both" />`

Answer (score 1):

easy way to define your div width:50% in style or use clear:both in br

Comment: I understand your sentiments. but thats a comment, not an answer to the Orignal Poster's question.